# "Manual" calculation of standard error is off, trying to calculate beta_estimator confidence interval of regression

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

```
# calculating the confidence intervall manually using numpy matrix operations ------------------------------------------------ #
# our least-squares estimator ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
beta_estimator_4dec
# the alpha for our confidence intervall ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
alpha
# the standard error of our least-squares estimator -------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
s_e = np.sqrt(est.mse_resid)

# appending intercept, estimator vifs
vif_lst = list()
for i in range(len(Xc.columns)):
    vif = variance_inflation_factor(exog = Xc.values, exog_idx = i)
    vif_lst.append(vif)
    
# degrees of freedom --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
n = est.nobs
k = len(X_train.columns)
df = n - (k + 1)

# \bar X , mean_X_j ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
X_means = np.mean(X_estimator, axis=0)

# sum squared of x_residuals ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
x_diffs_sq = np.empty_like(X_estimator)
for i in range(len(X_estimator)):
    x_diffs_sq[i, :] = (X_estimator[i, :] - X_means)**2

S_xx = np.sum(x_diffs_sq, axis=0)

# standard error for each \hat\beta ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
'''
std_error_estimator_lst = list()
for i in range(len(beta_estimator_4dec)):
    std = s_e * np.sqrt((1 / S_xx[i]) * vif_lst[i])
    std_error_estimator_lst.append(std)
    print(std)
'''

V = np.linalg.inv(np.transpose(X_estimator) @ X_estimator)

std_error_estimator_lst = list()
for j in range(len(beta_estimator_4dec)):
    v_jj = V[j][j]
    std = s_e * np.sqrt(v_jj)
    std_error_estimator_lst.append(std)
    
# t-value from table based on alpha and df ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
t_value = special.stdtrit(df, 1 - alpha)

# confidence intervals table ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
upper_ci_lst = list()
lower_ci_lst = list()

for j in range(len(beta_estimator_4dec)):
    intervall = t_value * std_error_estimator_lst[j]
    upper = round(beta_estimator_4dec[j] + intervall, 4)
    lower = round(beta_estimator_4dec[j] - intervall, 4)
    upper_ci_lst.append(upper)
    lower_ci_lst.append(lower)

index_lst = list()
for i in range(len(beta_estimator_4dec)):
    if i < 1:
        index_lst.append("const")
    else:
        index_lst.append("X_" +str(i-1))
    
ci_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[lower_ci_lst, upper_ci_lst], index=["0", "1"], columns=index_lst).transpose()
ci_df
```

https://github.com/MaximilianHauser/Multiple_Linear_Regression/blob/main/Multiple_Linear_Regression.ipynb

As you can see, when comparing the table with my calculation using numpy to the one generated using:
est.conf_int(alpha = alpha), they're off, can't find the error.

Didn't find anything off with the input values and didn't find anything off with the math, tried an alternative formula, still in there commented out.

I expected the numbers to match at least to the 3rd or 4th decimal.

Comment: The link is to the entire file/code on my github repository. You can contribute the solution on github, I'll accept the commit.

Comment: It does only seem to be the case when the model is underspecified.